# Triangular and other step functions in matlab

Tags: special-functions, matlab

As the title indicates, I need help on how to plot a triangular function in Matlab. e.g.

$ f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      1-|x|, & |x|< 0 \\
       \\
      0, & \text{otherwise} 
   \end{cases}$

As well as the functions

$ Af(x)=\begin{cases} 
      A & x\geq 0 \\
       \\
      0 & x<0
   \end{cases}$ 
and
$ -f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      -1 & x\geq 0 \\
       \\
      0 & x<0
   \end{cases}$

I tried and plotted the unit step function

$ f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      0 & x< 0 \\
       \\
      1 & x\geq0
   \end{cases}$

as

```
x=-50:50;
y=[zeros(1,50) ones(1,51)];
plot(x,y);
axis([-55 55 -0.2 1.3])
```

Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, to plot a function you 1) sample the domain, defining a vector `x`; 2) compute the images of those samples, obtaining a vector `y`; and 3) use `plot(x,y)` or similar.

When your desired function graph is composed of *straight lines*, to get a perfect graph you should choose the sample points as the "*corners*" of the graph. For example, for the triangular function you should use points with -1, 0, 1 plus some points further to the left and to the right:

```
x = [-3 -1 0 1 3];
y = [ 0  0 1 0 0];
plot(x,y)
axis([-4 4 -.2 1.2])
```

[image]

If the point has a *jump* discontinuity you should *duplicate* the corresponding x in order to get the jump properly. For example, for the step function you could do

```
x = [-3 0 0 3];
y = [ 0 0 1 1];
plot(x,y)
axis([-4 4 -.2 1.2])
```

[image]